# cmd /q not working as expected

Tags: windows, command-line-arguments, command-prompt, cmd

I want to start a command prompt but don't want any output from it. So I am starting it as -

```
cmd /q dir
```

which works fine but one cmd.exe doesn't exit. If I use this-

```
cmd /q /c  dir
```

I can see output of dir command which I don't expect to see

Comment: What the heck are you trying to do? `cmd /q /c rem` would have no output at all, but it would be a no-op. Why are you even calling `dir` if you don't want to run it? `/Q` just has the effect of `echo off`. Nothing more, nothing less. It doesn't suppress all output.

Comment: I am calling some other code, using dir just as an example. If I replace dir with mycode.exe, I don't want to see any output from mycode.exe

Comment: can you give the code you actually tried?

Comment: Why are you using CMD to run a binary executable?

Comment: because I am running it remotely via psexec

Comment: @user837208: psexec does not require the use of cmd.  (Except in special cases, such as specifying redirection at the remote end.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The /Q option does not disable output, it only turns ECHO OFF. It is not normally needed, but there are occasions where it becomes useful.

To disable all non-error output, simply redirect the stdout to nul (`>nul` or `1>nul`). If you also want to disable error output, then stderr must also be redirected (`2>nul`).

```
>nul 2>nul cmd /c dir
```

***Addendum***

Andriy M has a good point with his comment on the question. You can probably execute your command directly without going through CMD. Redirection would still work the same.

```
>nul 2>nul yourCommand.exe
```

Comment: @user837208: in your specific case, you should do the redirection on the remote system so that the output isn't sent over the network: psexec \\target cmd /c ">nul 2>nul yourCommand.exe"